# Using JQuery and ajax to connect to backend

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

I am implementing a Spring Boot application and implementing a front end that will use ajax to connect to the Sprint boot back end. This is the first time, that I am using a front end and require some help. I don't know where I am going wrong. I want to pass the JSON to the backend for further processing.

The code is located here https://github.com/rajivpjs/Customer-Inventory/tree/23_ConnectToBackEnd in folder customer/src/main/resources/static/js folder

The current implementation can be debugged in the Spring boot application, but is returning a null User and Customer object.

The ajax call is:

```
 $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/register/customer",
       data: JSON.stringify({ 
              "email":     $('#email').val(), 
              "pass":      $('#pass').val(), 
              "firstName": $('#firstName').val(), 
              "lastName":  $('lastName').val() }),
       dataType: "json",
       contentType : "application/json;charset=utf-8",
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert("data");
       },
       error: function(data) {
           alert(data);
       }
     });

     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Can you please help?

Thanks.

Comment: Never trust user input. use `.text()` instead of `.val()` to avoid xss https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

Comment: did you check the network tab? is the request body correct?

Comment: you can try this code: 
var jsonData = {};
jsonData.email = $('#email').val();
....
change it in data when POST and debug in network tab.

Comment: Yes, I checked the request body and it is coming in this format key=value&key=value and it it showing pplication/x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 0):

First thing to mention, is that you need to disable form submission using standard html `<input type='submit'>` and bind your ajax call on appropriate button click OR remove your ajax implementation and send your form using html `submit`. I will provide an example for you for the first case. I assume that you deleted `type=submit` from your form.

```
$("#your-button").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $("#signup-form").serialize();

    console.log(formData);
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/register/customer",
           data: formData,
           dataType: "json",
           contentType : "application/json;charset=utf-8",
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert("data");
           },
           error: function(data) {
               alert(data);
           }
         });
});
```

EDIT:

I am afraid that did not work. It errors on the backend saying JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'firstName': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false'.

Comment: I am afraid that did not work. It errors on the backend saying JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'firstName': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false'.

Comment: Just to give an update. I tried a curl request from the command line and that successfully works.

Comment: On backend your parameters should have the same name as form's inputs